# Debian did not work on USB

Tags: debian, dd, live-usb, gpt, mbr

I have been facing difficulties reinstalling Debian using the legacy and MBR approach on a GPT USB. Previously, I used to install Linux distributions on USB flashes and create a dd image for backup and sharing purposes. I had a 64GB USB with different Debian versions installed. The setup included a legacy installation with MBR using two partitions: a 1GB swap partition and a 12GB ext4 partition for system files. I ensured all firmwares were installed for compatibility.

However, the problem arose when I attempted to install Debian 12 stable. Opting for UEFI and GPT as the partition table, I created three partitions (EFI, swap, system files). I resized the partitions to reduce the dd image size. Consequently, I now have two dd images: the first one for the entire USB flash and the second created using the command:

`dd if=debian12_64GB.dd of=debian12_15GB.dd bs=512 count=[number of last used sector+1] status=progress seek=0`

Unfortunately, when I tried to burn debian12_15GB.dd onto a USB, it failed to work. After conducting research, I discovered that GPT uses the last few sectors for backup headers. Hence, I realized that my previous method of using MBR on a GPT USB was not applicable. Switching back to the legacy and MBR installation method, the installation process completed without errors. However, upon booting from the USB, I encountered a black screen with a blinking cursor.

To troubleshoot, I attempted to burn the Kali Linux live ISO on the same USB, and it worked flawlessly. I have tried various solutions, including cleaning the corrupted GPT using:

`wipefs -af <my USB name>`

which seemed to resolve the PMBR size mismatch message. Additionally, I tried recreating an empty GPT table using gdisk, but it did not solve the issue. I also cleared the table and created an MBR table, but the problem persisted.

I have spent more than a week searching for a solution without success. Can anyone provide guidance on how to successfully reinstall Debian using the legacy and MBR approach on a GPT USB, without encountering these problems? I have verified the installer integrity by comparing sha256sums and have attempted the process with different USB flashes, but the outcome remains the same. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess you mean boot in BIOS mode when you write MBR approach. Then you need a (small) partition with the flag `bios_grub` when using GPT. See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace) (which is about Ubuntu, but should be applicable on Debian too).